# How to use dictd as an offline dictionary in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-center, dictionary

I have installed dictd from Ubuntu Software Center in my Ubuntu 14.04. I want to use it as an offline dictionary but can't find it's application by pressing the superkey.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For others looking at this question, you may want to consider my new project:
https://github.com/mufeed20/pydict
It may just be what you are looking for but its in alpha. If possible, consider contributing.
Run 'pydict.py' in SFPD. This does not need you to install additional applications other than Python 3, dictd, dict-wn and python-gobject.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find in among the applications, because `dictd` in itself is a console application, you have to use a frontend application for it, e.g. `opendict` or `goldendict`.

In console, you would simple just write `dict [options] word`. You can look up the options at the `man` page of `dict`.

What I *did not* cover in this answer is the installation of a dictionary to the `dictd` database. As I have not used the software personally, I cannot provide a solution for this, but you may surely find guides for it on the internet.

Comment: kdictd is not there in the ububtu software center

Comment: how do I use it as dictionary using terminal?

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer your questions.

Comment: problem resolved thanx